# Authentication Required system policy prevents modifications of network settings for all users

Tags: networking

When I open Ubuntu a box open with the title "Authentication Required system policy prevents modifications of network settings for all users".

On this window i am not able to click and enter the password and stuck here.

Comment: Possibly this bug: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/704132 (you can try the workaround explained in the comments there)

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].